# netsh error on windows 2008 R2

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate, netsh

We are upgrading the server from Windows 2003 to 2008. As part of the process, I need to configure a port with a SSL certificate. When I ran the following command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=1.2.3.4:8000 certhash=certificatehash appid={someGUID}
```

I got the following error:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error:
>   1312 A specified logon session does
>   not exist. It may already have been
>   terminated.

When running the command prompt with an administrator does not resolve the issue. Notice that I did not run into this issue on Windows 2003 (using httpcfg) and that things work well there.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I've been following this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=VS.90).aspx and I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

the 1312 shows up at several occasions. aside from typos on the commandline, the other most common are:
- the certificate is not in your certificate store at all (check with MMC and 'certificates' snap-in)
- the certificate is in the wrong store: it should be in the store of 'local computer' not 'local user' (remember to choose proper account when activating the snapin inside the MMC)
- the certificate doesnt contain a Private Key (open the certificate and check whether it contains only public, or both keys)

I've spent over 1.5 hours before I found out that I've had generated a certificate succesfully, but misplaced some switches and it got written to a file without the private key:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from an elevated command prompt (not just as an admin)?. There's an [open source GUI tool](http://www.stevestechspot.com/CategoryView,category,AllContent.aspx) that drives the HTTP config APIs directly- I use it on 2008 R2 with no trouble (it auto-requests elevation via UAC). I've had mixed results with netsh/httpcfg. This one always works for me (and it behaves the same everywhere).